# Equation and bulleted list

Tags: latex, overleaf

I would like create an bulleted list that contain and equation, how can I do? I have tru this but is not working and it gives me error. The package is already present in the code

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{itemize}
\begin{align*}

\item X_i  it is a ...

\end{align*}
\end{itemize}
```

This is my base:
https://it.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-lucas/tnzgmxxqppwh

[image: My output]

Comment: Can you make a sketch how the result should look like? And please edit your code to all things necessary to compile it, e.g. a class and a `document` environment

Comment: I made the changes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your items seem to be mainly normal text, so I suggest to use inline math for the math parts:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item $X_i$  it is a ...
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]